# Determining the Cartesian product of a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question for one of my practice assignments and I'm not sure how to solve it;

For the set A = {1,2,3}, let U = $A^2$ = A x A be the Universal Set. For B = {1,2}, determine $\overline{B \times B}$

---

I'm a bit confused as to what the set A has to do with the problem. Also

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: First, figure out what $U$ is. Second, figure out what $B\times B$ is. Finally, use the first two pieces of information to figure out what $\overline{B\times B}$ is.

Each part is a matter of applying the relevant definition.

Comment: A \times A = {(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)}

Comment: Yes. That's step one.

Comment: B \times B = {(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)} I don't understand what to do after this however.

Comment: Okay. What does the line over $B\times B$ indicate? What do we mean when we put a line over a set?

Comment: Is that the complement of BxB with the universal set?

Comment: Precisely my suspicion! It can actually mean one of several things, depending on context, but it's probably that. Check your textbook and notes to confirm.